# DataGridCell and Custom Framework Element Content

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid

I am thinking about converting one of my apps over to WPF, and one of my main concerns was the performance of the `DataGrid` control (my user's computers are outdated XP machines with no dedicated graphics). I experimented with a few thousand rows and scrolling performance was horrible.

I was wondering if there is a way to set the datagrid cell's content to a custom class that derives from `FrameworkElement`?

Here is a sample class that appears to have much better performance when put in a virtualizing stackpanel:

```
public class LiteTextBlock : FrameworkElement
{
    private Size _mySize;
    private string _myText;
    private double totalWidth;
    private GlyphTypeface _typeface;
    private int _fontSize;
    private GlyphRun _run;

    public LiteTextBlock(Size mySize, string myText, GlyphTypeface typeface, int fontSize)
    {
        _mySize = mySize;
        this.Width = _mySize.Width;
        this.Height = _mySize.Height;
        _myText = myText + " additional information";
        _typeface = typeface;
        _fontSize = fontSize;
    }

    protected override void OnRender(DrawingContext drawingContext)
    {
        if (_run == null)
        {
            totalWidth = 0;

            ushort[] glyphIndexes = new ushort[_myText.Length];
            double[] advanceWidths = new double[_myText.Length];

            for (int i = 0; i < _myText.Length; i++)
            {
                ushort glyphIndex = _typeface.CharacterToGlyphMap[_myText[i]];
                double width = _typeface.AdvanceWidths[glyphIndex] * _fontSize;

                if (totalWidth + width >= _mySize.Width - 10)
                {
                    Array.Resize(ref glyphIndexes, i);
                    Array.Resize(ref advanceWidths, i);
                    break;
                }

                glyphIndexes[i] = glyphIndex;
                advanceWidths[i] = width;
                totalWidth += width;
            }

            Point origin = new Point(5, 0);

            _run = new GlyphRun(_typeface, 0, false, _fontSize, glyphIndexes
                , origin, advanceWidths, null, null, null, null, null, null);
        }

        drawingContext.DrawGlyphRun(Brushes.Black, _run);
    }
}
```

Can anyone show me if this is possible?

Disclaimer: I have already tried using lighter-weight controls such as the `ListView`, but performance was still poor.

Comment: Can you post the code / XAML that was giving you bad performance?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, there is a way.

You need to implement your custom [DataGridColumn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.datagridcolumn.aspx) and override its [GenerateElement](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.datagridcolumn.generateelement.aspx) method and you need to handle [DataGrid.AutoGeneratingColumn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.datagrid.autogeneratingcolumn.aspx) event to set your custom DataGridColumn to DataGrid.

Here is a sample for custom DataGridColumn:

```
public class DataGridLiteTextColumn : DataGridColumn
{
    private readonly PropertyDescriptor property;

    private readonly GlyphTypeface glyphTypeface = new GlyphTypeface(new Uri("file:///C:\\WINDOWS\\Fonts\\Arial.ttf"));

    public DataGridLiteTextColumn(PropertyDescriptor property)
    {
        this.property = property;
    }

    protected override FrameworkElement GenerateElement(DataGridCell cell, object dataItem)
    {
        var value = property.GetValue(dataItem);
        return new LiteTextBlock(new Size(100, 20), value != null ? value.ToString() : string.Empty, this.glyphTypeface, 10);
    }

    protected override FrameworkElement GenerateEditingElement(DataGridCell cell, object dataItem)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

Here is a handler for DataGrid.AutoGeneratingColumn event:

```
private void OnAutoGeneratingColumn(object sender, DataGridAutoGeneratingColumnEventArgs e)
{
    e.Column = new DataGridLiteTextColumn((PropertyDescriptor)e.PropertyDescriptor);
}
```

This code will work for displaying values, although LiteTextBlock constructor size parameters are probably not set to appropriate values. To edit values you must also implement [GenerateEditingElement](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.datagridcolumn.generateeditingelement.aspx) method.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the DataGrid's [EnableRowVirtualization](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.datagrid.enablerowvirtualization.aspx) property is set to True. It should be True by default, but make sure it wasn't set to False in a Style somewhere.

Answer (score 0):

`UI Virtualization` is enabled by default. But it gets disabled in either of the following scenarios -

1. The DataGrid has an unlimited height during the measure arrange process.
   If the DataGrid thinks it has enough space to arrange all items, then it will not virtualize anything.
   This usually happens when you place the DataGrid in a stackpanel.
2. The ItemsPanel of the datagrid.
   The virtualization is accomplished by the VirtualizingStackPanel. If you change the ItemsPanel, the VirtualizingStackPanel will be removed.
3. Items Grouping.
   In .NET4.0, virtualization does not support grouping. In some cases, assign a GroupStyle to the DataGrid will turn off the virtualization even if the items are not grouped.

Please check you are not falling in any of the scenarios mentioned above.

As a side note, you can also implement `Data Virtualization` on your Items Source of datagrid. Sample for the same with proofs can be found here - [Data Virtualization](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/34405/WPF-Data-Virtualization)